# Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code (I am a newbie in programming, pls do cooperate )

Tags: error-handling

I am trying to write a code which calculates the HCF of two numbers but I am either getting a error or an empty list as my answer[image: Here is my code]

I was expecting the HCF, My idea was to get the factors of the 2 given numbers and then find the common amongst them then take the max out of that

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information, please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For future reference, do not attach screenshots. Instead, copy your code and put it into a code block because stack overflow supports code blocks. To start a code block, write three tildes like ``` and to end it write three more tildes to close. If you add a language name like python, or javascript after the first three tildes, syntax highlighting will be enabled. I would also create a more descriptive title that more accurately describes the problem at hand. It would look like so:

Title: How to print from 1-99 in python?

```py
for i in range(1,100):
  print(i)
```

To answer your question, it seems that your HCF list is empty, and the python max function expects the argument to the function to not to be empty (the 'arg' is the HCF list). From inspection of your code, this is because the two if conditions that need to be satisfied before anything is added to HCF is never satisfied.

So it could be that hcf2[x] is not in hcf and hcf[x] is not in hcf[x] 2.

What I would do is extract the logic for the finding of the factors of each number to a function, then use built in python functions to find the common elements between the lists. Like so:

```py
num1 = int(input("Num 1:")) # inputs
num2 = int(input("Num 2:")) # inputs

numberOneFactors = []
numberTwoFactors = []
commonFactors = []

# defining a function that finds the factors and returns it as a list
def findFactors(number):
    temp =  []
    for i in range(1, number+1):
        if number%i==0:
            temp.append(i)
    return temp
            
numberOneFactors = findFactors(num1) # populating factors 1 list
numberTwoFactors = findFactors(num2) # populating factors 2 list

# to find common factors we can use the inbuilt python set functions.

commonFactors = list(set(numberOneFactors).intersection(numberTwoFactors))
# the intersection method finds the common elements in a set.
```